# Can't seem to group by content type in document sets

Tags: content-type, document-set

I created two content types based on Document, no extra metadata, called Status Report and Timesheet.

I then created a content type based on the Document Set called Project.  Added a couple of site columns of type Person and a managed metadata.  I then added Status Report and Timesheet as "Allowed Content Types" in document set settings.

I have created a library and added the Project content type.  That all works fine.  I can create new projects and assign metadata.  Inside the set I can create status reports and timesheets.

*My problem is that I want to create a view which will group the documents inside the document set.  I don't seem to have "Content type" in the group by drop down.*

I am able to add content type to the columns of the view.  It displays the correct data but I cannot sort or filter on this column.

Have I done something stupid?

Answer (score 1):

Use a workflow to copy the value of the content type field into a new text field, then use this field to group by.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and can't either. The easiest way is to simply edit the page in SharePoint Designer and do the grouping that way.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the content type is not available for grouping in Designer either... Or I don't know how to display it. I opened the AllItems.aspx and clicked Sort&Group in the ribbon. But the column Content Type isn't there. Can you give me a hint how to do it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Check out: http://www.sharepointanalysthq.com/2010/06/how-to-group-by-content-type-in-sharepoint-2010/